# How to update an array by index using the useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a select component that I would like to use to update the values of an array of objects based on the index.

**I use the hook like this:**

```
const [areas, setAreas] = useState(product.areas);
```

**This returns the following for "areas":**

```
[
  0: {de: "Getraenke", en: "Drinks"},
  1: {de: "Snacks", en: "Snacks"}
]
```

**My select component looks like this:**

```
{areas?.map((area: {de: string, en: string}, index: number) => (
  <Wrapper key={index}>
    <Select
      label="Area"
      name="product-area"
      value={area[lang] || ''}
      onChange={e => setArea([...area, { [lang]: e.target.value }])}
    >
      {areaOptions.map(option => (
        <option value={option} key={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </InputWrapper>
))}
```

**In this way I unfortunately get the following for "area" after selecting an option (here "Sweets"):**

```
[
  0: {de: "Getraenke", en: "Drinks"},
  1: {de: "Snacks", en: "Snacks"}
  2: {en: "Sweets" }
]
```

So the first object of the array is not updated as intended, but a further object is appended, which unfortunately also lacks the "de" language.

**My goal is to update the first object (or the object based on the index of the select component) of the array so that instead of:**

```
  0: {de: "Getraenke", en: "Drinks"}
```

..the updated object looks like this:

```
  0: {de: "Suessigkeiten", en: "Sweets"}
```

The objects within the array should therefore be updated based on the index of the current select component and also take into account the selected language (default "en").

Comment: In the `onChange`, you can write any logic you like... why don't you take "areas" array and modify/create a new array the way you want, and then call `setAreas` ?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to clone the array, update the specific array item by index and then replace the old array with it using useState, like this.

```
const updateArea = (e, lang, index) => {
  const updatedAreas = [...areas];
  updatedArea[index][lang] = e.target.value;
  setAreas(updatedAreas);
}

...

{areas?.map((area: {de: string, en: string}, index: number) => (
  <Wrapper key={index}>
    <Select
      label="Area"
      name="product-area"
      value={area[lang] || ''}
      onChange={e => updateArea(e, lang, index)}
    >
      {areaOptions.map(option => (
        <option value={option} key={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </InputWrapper>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach was sufficient for my use case. I have adapted it for newly created input fields (if no index is available yet). Works  :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve this step by step

#### 1. A further object is appended

That's because you're telling it to do so :)

```
onChange={e => setArea([...area, { [lang]: e.target.value }])}
```

This means, copy the entire array `...area` and add a new object at the end `{ [lang]: e.target.value }`

Another mistake you're making is not using a callback function, proper way to access current `...area` should be this:

```
onChange={e => setArea((currentArea) => [...currentArea, { [lang]: e.target.value }]}
```

This way you always have the most up-to-date version of `area`.

Now, to update the specific object by the index, you would do the following:

```
onChange={e => setArea((currentArea) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  
  const newArea = currentArea.map((singleArea, areaIndex) => {
    if (areaIndex === index) {
      return { [lang]: value }
    }
 
    return singleArea;
  });

  return newArea;
}}
```

#### 2. Lacks the "de" language

Again, you're explicitly only adding one language to it :)

```
{ [lang]: value } // { en: 'something' }
```

Not sure how to fix this one for you, but at least you can understand why its wrong, It should be something like (just a concept, this won't work):

```
{ [langDe]: value, [langEn]: value } // { de: 'Guten Tag', en: 'something' }
```

Comment: Ok, the update by index seems to work like this. But I have problems with the language. I changed your approach like this: if (areaIndex === index) {return {... singleArea, [lang]: e.target.value}}. If I choose a new option this first time, it works. With the next update I get the following error message: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released / nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist ()

Comment: @Codehan25 I've edited my code to destructure value event and persist it in a constant. Try with updated code. `const { value } = e.target;` and then replace `e.target.value` with `value`

Comment: Thank you for your approach. For my use case I took the solution from Elijah Enuem-Udogu. This also made it easier for the languages and the code had fewer lines. The 3 return statements in the onChange handler also confused me a bit. But thank you anyway :)